# Ubuntu Server - Upload and download files using Java client

Tags: java, ubuntu, server, ubuntu-server

I'm a newbie with server programming and currently I was trying to create a client/server application with java to storage and retrieve files into and from a remote ubuntu server. I tried to look something like this on the Internet but I found nothing useful to my case and now I'm asking even if is that possible.

Furthermore, I know that I should write both client and server sides, but how can I upload and run server side, you know... on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats very possible - there seems to be plenty of stuff on google [here's one example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html).

In answer to your second part: the trick is to run both the client and the server on your own computer, and the client connects (over the loopback ip address "localhost") to the same machine.

Comment: what do you mean with "loopback ip address 'localhost' " ? Shouldn't I use my server IP?

Comment: If the server is running on the same computer as the client, then you can use "127.0.0.1" or  "localhost" (which is the address of "me"), the computer will essentially send out a message that "loops back" to itself. The IP is a property of the computer, not of the program running on it.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear at the beginning, it's a remote server on a different computer so that's why asked how to upload and run server side

Comment: Yeah perhaps you could reword your question a tad. Are you asking how to upload a program that you have written to a server that you have? What kind of server is it? If its another computer that you own, a simple answer would be to use a memory stick and run the program on the other computer? For a remote server, look into using "ssh" or talk to the server administrator

Comment: Actually I have installed an ubuntu server on a a computer that I've connected to my local network and I am using it as remote server. If I succed moving and run a Java file on this server, do you think that the sample you posted me could work? (Obviously changing the Ip address )

Comment: Oh okay, in which case yes use that server's IP. Yeah it looks like a good place to start from. I would also recommend the ZMQ library as a nice way of doing networking (its a bit simpler than sockets). It might be a good idea to test it on your own machine with loopback first though - less chance of firewalls getting in the way etc

Comment: I'll try it! Thx, so useful